# PHP Calender Multiple Day Events

Tags: php, events, calendar

I've created a calender which works perfectly however I need to be able to insert events which run over multiple days. The calender shows events for AM and PM for single days, but when entering an event over multiple days, the event shows on the days between the event start and finish date. I am using timestamps for the start and end times. Here is my current SQL:

```
$day_start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $cMonth, ($i - $startday + 1), $cYear);
$day_morning_end = mktime(11, 59, 59, $cMonth, ($i - $startday + 1), $cYear);
$day_afternoon_start = mktime(12, 0, 0, $cMonth, ($i - $startday + 1), $cYear);
$day_end = mktime(23, 59, 59, $cMonth, ($i - $startday + 1), $cYear);

$morn_sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE (start_stamp>='$day_start' AND end_stamp<='$day_morning_end') OR (start_stamp<'$day_start' AND end_stamp>'$day_end')";
```

There is another query for the afternoon. As I said, it works fine except showing events on the day they start and finish, but it shows it on the days in between.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested cause i don't have the table/data but i hope this will help. :)

```
    $day_sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_events 
       WHERE start_stamp BETWEEN '$day_start' AND '$day_end' 
            AND end_stamp BETWEEN '$day_start' AND '$day_morning_end'
                OR end_stamp BETWEEN '$day_afternoon_start' AND '$day_end'";
```